# Google play not updating my app automatically for new version

Tags: android, google-play, auto-update

I uploaded my app on play store, and then uploaded a new version of the app. However, I didn't get any notification to update my app. It seems to have updated automatically to the new version.

I have chosen the option to update app over wi-fi only. Many other apps get updated automatically but mine is not. Why is that?

Comment: Facing the same issue. I have submitted for update without any new permission, yet google play does not update it without me clicking update button. Were you able to find any alternate solution for this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [App not updating for alpha testers on google play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751720/app-not-updating-for-alpha-testers-on-google-play)

Answer (score 2):

It will take around 24 hours for giving update notification to users. Check this document for your reference. [Upload your APK](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

It takes some time for google play to reflect the update to devices, from few hours to days. So give it some hours, and hopefully you'll see the update notification in google play in you device.

Comment: I have checked on play store it showing update button for my app, but thing is that neither its auto updating my nor  sending notification for it.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. It's not auto-updating for users who are actually capable of manually downloading the update. I've tried this on friends' phone whenever I know my app has been updated. It shows that the app is available to update, but they never got a notification, and even my friends who have my app set to auto-update are not having their app update automatically. Unfortunately I have no idea what the problem could be.

Comment: did you find the solution @bluemunch  I have the same issue. My clients are not happy with it. If you had found the solution please share to us as well bros

Answer (score 0):

If you have turned on AUTO UPDATE option in settings then it would be automatically updated

otherwise you will receive notification that "New version is available on play store"

If you want to check it http://www.androidcentral.com/updating-your-android-apps-choosing-automatic-or-manual-and-how-get-it-done

Comment: Neither it getting auto updated nor throwing notification, Auto update is on over wi-fi and i am conected to wi-fi only

Answer (score 0):

because you added a new permission  to the new  apk google play will not auto update your app