# App published 2 weeks ago still does not update Play store

Tags: android, google-play, apk, updates

As the title says, we published a new version of an app 2 weeks ago. Play Store indicates in the registry that the new version was uploaded (1.7), and allows it to be downloaded to users who did not have it. Not so, for those who already have it, for example, users who have version 1.6, do not see the option to update, just uninstall or open.

We expected it to be only a matter of time, but 2 weeks is already too much. We contacted Google support, and they only ask us questions like: "Have automatic updates for the application enabled?" ... Does anyone know what is happening, or if it is our mistake, some step wrongly made? We generate the apk directly from Android Studio and change the version.

Answer (score 1):

One of the issues that your users might have is this

[image]

Maybe they disabled the auto-updates of Google Play, but is really weird that they can't see it, maybe it's due the devices. Is your device listed as compatible with the new version of your app? Did you tried clearing Google Play cache and trying it again?

PS: Make sure you change in your Gradle (Module app) your versionCode along with the VersionName

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering friend. Yes, we have reviewed all these options on all our devices, all are compatible with the exception of one tablet (the app is published in beta, this should not influence the updates either), we also clean the Playstore cache, but it still has no result ... Thank you very much.

Comment: also please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751720/app-not-updating-for-alpha-testers-on-google-play

Comment: Yes, we also review the beta application tab @Gastón Saillén

Comment: Are you sure that you put the greater version that previous.

Comment: yes, like Meghshyam says, check your versionCode in your gradle, you need to change it along the version name too

Comment: Yes Srs, version code 6 and version name 1.6, actually was uploaded version code 7 and version name 1.7  @MeghshyamSonar

Comment: @CJara is your problem solved,i also having same issue in my new update i only change  small function.all my version code and name is greater, i already reladed 27 updates this my new update, its been 3 days its still processing. is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

If new users are getting the new version installed then it is definitely uploaded to the Play store correctly.

If existing users aren't seeing "update" (just open) then it means there is something about the new version of the app that is incompatible with their devices. You can check this by trying uninstalling and re-installing. If they get the old version after an uninstall / re-install (or worse, if they can't install after uninstalling) it shows that only the old version is compatible with their device.

This probably means you changed something in the manifest to make it incompatible, but that is a whole different debugging problem.

Comment: I'm not sure about that, the problem is with all devices.