# App not updating for Alpha testers on Play Store for some Internal users

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

After releasing our app for a few internal users via the Play Store Internal test track, we moved to closed Alpha testing. However, for some of our Alpha testers, the new update of the app is not visible at all. All of these users have opted-in to be part of this test track too but, when they access the app listing on Play Store app, they see an older release and not a build that was released several hours ago.

Some of these users even see the update that was pushed a week ago! Even for one of the developers who has access to the Play Console who got the notification of the update gone live when tried to go to the app listing sees an older version only. What's surprising is that these same users can see the latest version on the web version of Play Store.

I've tried multiple solutions based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751720/app-not-updating-for-alpha-testers-on-google-play) like Play Store Force Stop + cache clear + data clear + network change, etc. Nothing worked for me.

Comment: Does the release you're expecting them to see have a higher release code number than all the others?

Comment: @nasch yes, the release has a higher code number. The app is still in closed alpha stage only so, this is where we're pushing all our updates.

Comment: OK I have nothing then, sorry.  Good luck and contact support.   Be patient, it could be 2-3 days before they get back to you.

Comment: Those who don't want to wait can use 'internal app sharing' instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Having faced a similar problem, I had a chat with one of the Play Console support rep. After verifying the release sanity using the app package name, the rep gave me following answer:

> Please note, due to device connectivity and varying server load, it may take several days (in some cases a week) for app updates to reach all devices. The behavior you are seeing with the update being available on the web is common for apps. The mobile store will update in due course.

However, at the end he asked me to try out one thing - since its mostly the internal users who are not seeing the update, I should ask all of these users to opt-out of the internal test track and then re-opt-in to the alpha test track. He hypothesised that since I'm only releasing updates in the alpha track now, Internal track may be creating an issue with app updates for these users.

It actually worked for us! Give it a try.