# Play store updates not reflected. It shows version changes in site, but not in app

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

We had a version 1.7 in beta, next we released an update 1.8 on production. The updates were live within few hours. But the update time was showing wrong. It was showing time before. We published at 8:05 AM, but we got the following notification:

Your update to appname, created on Mar 13, 2020, 2:51 AM, is live in the store.

Once we search, we could see the content (updates) given in the play store and the app version to be correct, but the application did not reflect the latest changes.

Also, when viewing on the web, it shows updated on 13 March, but in our mobiles, it shows updated on March 12.

Has anyone faced this issue? What maybe the issues ?

Comment: There is sometimes a delay between platforms to update and reflect all the changes for the google play store. They said it them self that it may take more time to propagate all the changes to everyone even tho you received the notification about updates being live. [Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17751917/2911633) it is talking about alpha release but it is the same for all channels

Comment: we released a beta soon after it, which came out soon.